# prevent duplicates when select rows by RAND() and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to select rows and order them by `RAND()` and it works fine without any repetitions. But when i limit rows it keeps getting duplicated ones.

Let's say that i have a SHOW MORE button to get more results with `AJAX` and each click must change the limit (Where should rows start at and how many rows should be fetched). But Here i keep getting duplicated rows.

Here is my line:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20,20
```

I think that `RAND()` doesn't care whether `LIMIT` exists or not, it will always starts fetching rows at anywhere it likes randomly but limit how many rows must be fetched .

Anyway is there anything to do with it?

Comment: `RAND()` only works for the single execution, it does not remember what it did last time it was executed

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is bad solution. The indexes  will be ignored. For large amounts of data you will have less performance

Comment: So guys i can't ```rand``` and ```limit``` the rows at sametime?

Comment: Create a random integer, perhaps in php or MySQL before querying the first 20 rows and save it somewhere e.g. session. Let's say it is 1234. Then in your order by clause use `order by rand(1234)`. As long as same constant is provided to rand, it'll produce same sequence of numbers. When you query the next 20 rows with same seed the rows will be ordered just the way they did for first invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep id of already shown results in an variable and exclude it from select next time

```
SELECT * FROM products 
where id not in (1, 7, 9) // id from variable
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20,20
```

Comment: it seems nice way! i'll try it 

Comment: i don't know if this is the only way to do that or there is another way without keeping IDs of the previous results. But I will accept this answer as it helped me anyways.